# websocket connection fails?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, websocket

I'm new in web sockets and trying to create one using asp.net Generic Handler and JavaScript WebSocket Class

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload= function () {

        var name = prompt('what is your name?:');            
        var url = 'ws://localhost:5707/ws.ashx?name=' + name;    
        var ws = new WebSocket(url);    
        ws.onopen = function () {
            alert('Connection Opened');
        };
            ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        };
            ws.onclose = function () {
            alert('Connection Close');
        };
            ws.onerror = function (e) {
            alert('Error')
        };

        }

</script>
```

C# Generic Handler Called ws.ashx

```
public class ws : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new TestWebSocketHandler());
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Class TestWebSocketHandler which is inherits from WebSocketHandler

```
   public class TestWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler
    {
        private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();
        private string name;

        public override void OnOpen()
        {
            this.name = this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["name"];
            clients.Add(this);
            clients.Broadcast(name + " has connected.");
        }

        public override void OnMessage(string message)
        {
            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} said: {1}", name, message));
        }

        public override void OnClose()
        {
            clients.Remove(this);
            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} has gone away.", name));
        }

    }
```

My Problem is

when the websocket intend to open i noticed that when went to the handler the

```
context.IsWebSocketRequest // returns false
```

and then it fires Error on the client says

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:5707/ws.ashx?name=j

and then close the connection instantiation

i need to know where is the problem ? kindly

i'm using vs 2013 under windows 7 and i think its IIS 6 which i work on

Comment: Have you used fiddler or similar to see what is being sent/received?

Comment: no but how it will helps

Comment: actually, you might need to use the firefox tools; change to the network tab, find the web-socket connection, and look at the headers. For example, here's mine from this site (stackoverflow.com): http://i.stack.imgur.com/goQTY.png - what do you get against your site? Also: does it work in, say, Chrome?

Comment: no it works in non of the top 5 browsers :(

Answer (score 5):

WebSockets will only work on ASP.NET applications running on Windows 8 or Windows 2012 I am afraid. Despite of the API been included on .NET 4.5.1, it won't work if you are not using those operating system. Actually, if you try to use the `ClientWebSocket` it will throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

If you cannot get any of those operating systems, you can check alternatives:

- XSocket.NET: http://xsockets.net/
- SuperWebSocket : http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/
- Alchemy Websocket: http://alchemywebsockets.net/
- WebSocketListener : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: may be you're right but what are these tools in the references you gave me uses to deal with websockets on .net/ on the other hand i use .net framework 3.5.1 does it not supports websockets ?? or its related to IIS Version ??

Comment: @Marwan ah, I didn't see the Win 7 - it is the OS version that matters; the web-sockets layer that this uses is baked into http.sys; however, there are alternative web-sockets APIs available, if you genuinely can't use a different OS

Comment: They all probably use plain sockets. I developed `WebSocketListener`, and it uses a normal `TcpListener` to get `Socket` objects and negotiate a WebSocket session. I will not work in 3.5.1 though. What new  http.sys provides is the ability of transforming a normal HTTP request into a WebSocket connection, so you can run your websockets in the same port than your webpages. In the other hand, those alternatives that I put, need to be run in a different port as a service external to IIS. MS tells this was a change too big for introduce it in Windows 7 or Windows server 2008.

Comment: @vtortola of course, one option there is to simply use a NLB to send requests destined to the web-socket server to different backend nodes. Not what we do ourselves (we use a different domain for web-sockets), but it should work.

Comment: I've gone far that i can't get it i think i need a little research about networking and deep into windows ports and such a stuff so any references suggested

Comment: Recommended: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545 . You can read the book for free online.

Comment: There is a chapter about WebSockets that is actually quite good: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch17.html But you need to understand a little bit of TCP first (the book does a good introduction)

Answer (score 2):

Reason could be any of these:

1. Having IIS version < 8
2. Not enabled Web Socket Protocol under windows features
3. Having .NET Framework version < 4.5
4. Not included the following lines in web.config's `system.webServer` section:

```xml
<handlers>
    <add path="/ws.ashx" verb="*" name="ws" type="namespace.ws"/>
</handlers>
```